# Each character just after its consecutive occurrences

Tags: algorithm, go

I'm solving this problem using Go:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-frequency-of-each-character-just-after-its-consecutive-occurrences/

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    str := "GeeeEEKKKss"
    strArr := strings.Split(str, "")

    for i := 0; i < len(strArr); i++ {

        count := 1
        nxtIdx := i + 1
        for nxtIdx < len(strArr) && strArr[nxtIdx] == strArr[i] {
            i++
            count++
        }

        fmt.Print(strArr[i], strconv.Itoa(count))

    }
    fmt.Println()

}
```

> When I'm directly using i+1 in place of "nxtIdx" variable, I'm getting expected result
>    : G1e3E2K3s2
>
> https://play.golang.org/p/wJBpNbIzlNd
>
> But when I'm using "nxtIdx" variable, I'm getting unexpected result
>    : G1E4E1s4s1
>
> https://play.golang.org/p/g8hejYTv2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you do not increment `nxtIdx` inside the loop that affects loop iteration.

```
nxtIdx := i + 1
for nxtIdx < len(strArr) && strArr[nxtIdx] == strArr[i] {
    i++ // Here 
    count++
}
```

You should increment the `nxtIdx` also

```
nxtIdx := i + 1
for nxtIdx < len(strArr) && strArr[nxtIdx] == strArr[i] {
    i++ 
    nxtIdx++
    count++
}
```